# How can I make billiard without using Rigidbody?

Tags: unity, physics, networking

Unity's physics engine isn't deterministic (ie. the results aren't always the same on all computers) so I haven't Idea that how billiard games Implemented.Is there a way to Implementing fake and deterministic 
physic in unity?
I mean I want to make billiard without using Rigidbody

http://www.bezzmedia.com/swfspot/tutorials/flash8/8_Ball_Pool

I found this open source project that didn't use physic! this is what I need but unfortunately it's full c++ and I haven't enough time to convert it to c#

http://downloads.sourceforge.net/foobillard/foobillard-3.0-win32-2-bin.zip

Comment: id have expected all that to be uniform across all platforms

Comment: @BugFinder what do you mean ? can you explain more

Comment: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1421193/deterministic-physics-options.html

Comment: @Zibelas hi I saw it before but it's wrong because results is different and unity physics is non deterministic.unfortunately I loose my hope! I don't know how can I make multiplayer billiard?

Comment: @Zibelas Do you have a test where there arr more than two collisions on a single body? I know at least ODE randomizes the order in wich collision points are resolved in order to attempt exiting "deadlocks".

Comment: I read in photon forums that instead of using physics Vector3.Reflect used to make billiard balls move in reflected direction in network

Comment: @SeyedMortezaKamali the results of impacting a ball at an angle, applying force, should be the same on all

Comment: @BugFinder: no, neither PhysX nor Box2D guarantee identical results on different binaries/hardware. You can check their documentation to confirm this.

Comment: @BugFinder after many searching I found this :) http://www.bezzmedia.com/swfspot/tutorials/flash8/8_Ball_Pool

Comment: So @SeyedMortezaKamali, you started by [searching for existing guides to this classic physics problem](https://www.google.com/search?q=billiard+physics), including [game-specific guides](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3015/pool_hall_lessons_fast_accurate_.php) and [existing Q&A here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/129977/39518) and made your best effort to implement it based on all of this research, correct? What have you tried so far, and where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @DMGregory I edited my question and reopened my question

Comment: I don't see anything in the edit that makes this not a duplicate anymore. Can you explain what your question is asking, if it's not "how can I compute the movements of billiard balls"?

Comment: @DMGregory I want to make custom fake physic that is deterministic

Comment: What specific aspect of this is not served by the links you've shared in your question, and offered in the comments above?

Comment: [This seems really hard](https://gafferongames.com/post/floating_point_determinism/) to achieve. Are you sure you need it? Why don't you use an authoritative server instead?

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt it seems this is better solution thanks and It should work I will read article also I found this https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/server/current/reference/authoritative-server

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt I found an article that shows client-side prediction.can I use this in my billiard game? http://www.codersblock.org/blog/client-side-prediction-in-unity-2018

Comment: I don't know, I haven't tried it. You should try it :)